# How can I check whether two numbers are within "x" significant figures of the precision limits of the floating point type?

Tags: c++, c++11

So suppose we have a float type XType in which we have two numbers:

```
XType const a = 1.2345
XType const b = 1.2300
```

Then I want a function IsClose(XType const f1,XType const f2,unsigned const truncated_figures) such that

```
// the numbers are equal if the last two figures are ignored (1.23 == 1.23)
IsClose<XType>(a,b,2) == true

// the numbers are not equal if only the last is ignored (1.234 != 1.230)
IsClose<XType>(a,b,1) == false
```

So far I have this ugly mess, but I'm yet to convince myself it's correct:

```
// check if two floating point numbers are close to within "figures_tolerance" figures of precision for the applicable type
template <typename FloatType>
bool const IsClose(FloatType const f1, FloatType const f2, unsigned const figures_tolerance)
{
  FloatType const tolerance_exponent = std::pow(10.0,figures_tolerance);
  FloatType const tolerance = 
    std::pow(tolerance_exponent,std::log10(f1)) * 
    std::numeric_limits<FloatType>::epsilon()
  ;
  return std::abs(f1 - f2) < tolerance;
}
```

My reasoning is that the tolerance should be the epsilon raised to the order of magnitude that the number exceeds or subseeds 1.0 (the significant figures for which the epsilon is based). Does this make sense? Is there a better, more reliable way?

EDIT: My solution using the template function is below (it is based on user763305's answer below)

```
// check if two floating point numbers are within the last n digits of precision for the
// largest of the two numbers being compared.
template <typename FloatType>
bool const IsWithinPrecision(FloatType const f1, FloatType const f2, unsigned const n = 1U)
{
    FloatType const f_ref = std::max(std::abs(f1), std::abs(f2));
    FloatType const distance = std::abs(f1 - f2);
    FloatType const e = std::numeric_limits<FloatType>::epsilon();

    return distance < std::pow((FloatType) 10.0, (FloatType) n) * e * f_ref;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your question conflates different things. If you are trying to estimate how much error there could be in floating-point types, then it is impossible to do it with a formula, because the error depends on the specific operations and values used. It varies greatly between different kinds of computations and can range from zero to infinity.

Comment: On the other hand, if you are trying to determine whether two numbers are the same in the first `x` significant digits, then this code is wrong. The epsilon of the floating-point type would not be much involved. You would determine the first `x` digits of each and then compare them.

Comment: `IsClose` sounds a little subjective, I would assume `IsClose(1.2345,1.2300)` is close no matter the figure tolerance. But wait, that also depends on the context its used in, if the little precision is a big matter, then `IsClose` between the two isn't close. In what context will you use this mostly?

Comment: However, that sort of comparison is troublesome. The two numbers 1.6999999999999999 and 1.7000000000 differ in their first two significant digits but are very close to each other. You might want some other test of whether two numbers are close together or not.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil I'm trying to find whether the difference between two numbers is within a certain number of decimal points of precision of the first number, if that makes sense.

Comment: @ausairman: Why? Where do these numbers come from? Why are you trying to compare them? Why do you care about their decimal forms rather than how far apart they are regardless of the digits of the numerals?

Comment: @Eric Postpischil it's mainly for debugging. I want to test whether a number is correct by checking it against a different debugging method that calculates the same thing, but more slowly. The two methods are logically equivalent but because of precision limits the floats do not compare equally. Moreover, the order of magnitude varies so I need a test that always adjusts the epsilon by the order of magnitude of the numbers. This was my attempt at a solution.

Comment: For example, if I have 3e100 then two very close numbers might be billions apart, but if the numbers are closer to 3e1 then two close numbers might have a minuscule difference. I need a consistent way of measuring difference as relayed to number type precision, not dependant on magnitude.

Comment: @ausairman: Then what you want does not involve the digits of the numbers. And, since it is just for debugging, you can be lax about the test. Likely what you want is a simple test of relative error, such as `fabs(f1/f2 - 1) < SomeNumber`. Be aware, though, that certain computations can produce errors that are not relative to the computed values, in which case other tests may be necessary.

Comment: There is a function float_distance in boost, which computes the difference in ULP: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/utils/next_float/float_distance.html . ULP basically tells how many different representable floats are between the two numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test whether two numbers are within `n` significant digits of each other, use the inequality

```
abs(a - b) < pow(0.1, n) * max(abs(a), abs(b))
```

However, I usually find it more useful to test if the number of significant digits is at least the maximum possible number of significant digits (given the precision of the floating point type) minus `n`. This can be done using the inequality

```
abs(a - b) < pow(10.0, n) * std::numeric_limits<...>::epsilon() * max(abs(a), abs(b))
```

In other words, `n` is the number of significant digits we have *lost* through rounding errors. Something like `n = 2` or `3` usually works in practice.

The reason this works is that the distances between a floating point number `a` and the next representable floating point numbers below and above `a` lie between

```
0.5 * std::numeric_limits<...>::epsilon() * abs(a)
```

and

```
std::numeric_limits<...>::epsilon() * abs(a)
```

Also, the above inequality does not work if you are dealing with very small, or more precisely, denormal numbers. Then you should instead use the inequality

```
abs(a - b) < pow(10.0, n) * max(
    std::numeric_limits<...>::epsilon() * max(abs(a), abs(b)),
    std::numeric_limits<...>::denorm_min()
)
```

Comment: so quantitatively, if we had fudge = pow(10,n), would "n" represent the number of significant figures of tolerance?

Comment: My head hurts from all this precision talk and this answer seems legit. I'll use it. Thanks!

Comment: I've added my own adaption of your answer to the OP, using the template design I had initially used. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is just for debugging, it may be possible to be lax and use a simple test for relative error, such as:

```
if (fabs(f1 - f2) <= SomeNumber * fabs(f2)) ThingsAreGood else ThingsAreBad;
```

This supposes that `f2` is the known good (or at least known-to-be-better) value and that the error from rounding in floating-point operations is proportional to `f2`. Note that computations can produce errors in complicated ways. For example, if various other values were added to and subtracted from `f1` along the way, so that intermediate values had much larger magnitudes than the final result represented by `f2`, then the rounding errors may be proportional to those large intermediate values rather than to `f2`. In this case, you may need to compute an error threshold based on the intermediate calculations rather than on `f2`.

Comment: I'd suggest eliminating the division altogether, because then `f2` can be zero (otherwise, you'll get a divide by zero error).

Answer (score 0):

Taking care of the situation pointed out by Eric Postpischil as well, This function tells whether the 2 numbers are close enough or not according to the precision.

```
bool const IsClose(FloatType const f1, FloatType const f2, unsigned const figures_tolerance)
{
    FloatType res = f1-f2;
    res = res*pow(10.0,figures_tolerance);
    return !bool(int(res));
}
```

Comment: Cool, this looks like a good solution. "float" should be FloatType though right?

Comment: -1: This looks like something from an obfuscated code contest. All you are doing is to test `abs(f1-f2) < pow(10.0, -figures_tolerance)`

Answer (score 0):

The solution used in the edit answer did not work in my case for large number comparison.

I wrote a function using string comparison with a given digit precision

```cpp
#include <iomanip>

/**
 * Compare two number with a given digit precision
 *
 * @tparam T - Number precision
 *
 * @param n1 - First number to compare
 * @param n2 - Second number to compare
 * @param n - The first n digits that must be equals between the two numbers
 *
 * @return True if the n first digits of the two numbers are equals, false otherwise
 */
template<typename T>
bool isEqual(T n1, T n2, int n)
{
    int                index = 0;
    std::ostringstream a, b;

    a         << std::setprecision(n);
    b         << std::setprecision(n);
    std::cout << std::setprecision(n);
    a         << std::fixed;
    b         << std::fixed;
    std::cout << std::fixed;

    a << n1;
    b << n2;

    while (a.str()[index] == b.str()[index] && index < n) {
        index++;
    }

    if (index != n) {
        std::cout << "n1 != n2\n\nn1 = " << a.str() << "\nn2 = " << b.str() << "\ndiffer at index " << index << std::endl;
    }

    return index == n;
}
```